# Регулярное выражение для хэш тегов на PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите написать регулярку для хештегов. В качестве примера, привёл правильные и неправильные.

```
#11 - не должно считаться за хэштег
#ff - ОК
#1f - ОК
#f1 - ОК
```

Т.е если только цифры, то не должно считать хэштегом.

Желательно код с функцией `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/#\b.*[a-z]+.*\b/i
```

Код полностью:

```
$sourse = "#11 - не должно считаться за хэштег
#ff - ОК
#1f - ОК
#f1 - ОК";

$pattern = "/#\b.*[a-z]+.*\b/i";

preg_match_all($pattern, $sourse, $return);

var_dump($return);
```

Comment: @lampa, спасибо. А как добавить ещё чтобы входили знаки препинания? Например #1f,. "точка" и "запятая" и ещё, почему он учитывает все знаки и т.д? Как учитывать только #text и всё? А если написать #text test, то #text test считается хэштегом.

Comment: @ModaL     

     $return = preg_replace("/#(\d*[a-z.,]+\d*)/i", "<a href='/tags/$1'>$1</a>", $sourse);